# Actions on Google: Account Linking access_token issue

Tags: oauth, account, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am currently using implicit flow to link user's account for Google assistant use. The linking works perfectly, the user is redirected to my website to login, user logs in and is redirected to the following url with `access_token` generated by the website.

```
https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/YOUR_PROJECT_ID#access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&token_type=bearer&state=STATE_STRING
```

Google.com page is now displayed, which I assume means account linking has been successful. The problem however is on subsequent calls the `access_token` sent to API.ai is different then the one I sent back as a URL parameter.

I am failing to understand why this is?

**NOTE:** I am testing on Google Home Web simulator

Answer (score 0):

For starters, check to make sure the other parameters in the URL for the google.com page actually do indicate a success. They may show an error.

If you are repeatedly testing with the same user, you may need to remove permissions to your application in between each test. You can do this at https://myaccount.google.com/permissions.

Since tokens never expire with the Implicit Flow, it is possible that Google is using an old token and never accepting one of the new tokens you're issuing, but always using the original token you issued.